# Joi validation length of concatenation of two fields

Tags: joi

I have to validate the total length of two fields.

```
const schema = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    fieldOne: Joi.string().required()
    fieldTwo: Joi.string().required()
  })
};
```

What I want to check is that

```
`${fieldOne || ''} ${fieldTwo || ''}`.trim().length < 30
```

Is this something that can be achieved with Joi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a third field. That is a concat of the two and has a max length of 30. So, validate the individual fields and the combination of the two.

```
myObject.fieldOneTwo = `${fieldOne || ''} ${fieldTwo || ''}`.trim()
```

```
const schema = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    fieldOne: Joi.string().required(),
    fieldTwo: Joi.string().required()
    fieldOneTwo: Joi.string().limit(30, 'utf8').required()
  })
};
```

Alternatively, you could make the third field be the length of the other two and check it is a number < 30.